# Conversion from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql

I have this SQL Server query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetBuyHoldSellValuationAdjusted_PE]
    (@userName VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @companyCode VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @portfolioCode VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @regionCode VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @sectorCode VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @countryCode VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @recommend VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @universe VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
     @includeWatches BIT = NULL,
     @economicClassificationCode VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
     @InvestmentTypeCode VARCHAR(20) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
```

How to convert this part to Oracle PL/SQL version?

Comment: SO is NOT a free code writing service.

Comment: Try something first !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create procedure usp_GetBuyHoldSellValuationAdjusted_PE (
    userName in varchar2 default null,
    companyCode in varchar2 default null,
    . . .
    includeWatches in number default null,
    economicClassificationCode in varchar2 default null,
    InvestmentTypeCode in varchar2 default null
)
as
begin
```

The differences are:

- No `@` in the parameter name.
- No length required for strings -- and `varchar2` is the preferred data type.
- Explicitly showing `in` and `out` or both.
- Using `default` for default values.
- Doing something about the `bit` data type.